# Jquery - on button click, remove last available row

Tags: jquery

Here, Want to remove complete row if X is clicked. This works fine.

If user clicked 'add-item2' X.. it removes 'add-item2'. So, 'add-item1' & 'add-item3' will be available for user to fill in.

**But, our required functionality. If user clicked 'add-item2' X.. it have to check and remove 'last available' row. Ex: 'add-item3' have to remove in this sample.**

**So, 'add-item1' & 'add-item2' will be available for user to fill in.**

**HTML:**

```
<div class="row" id="add-more--names">
    <div class="row-names" id="add-name1">
        <div class="firstname form-validate">
            <input type="text" id="firstname-1" class="name-validator" name="First Name" >
        </div><div class="lastname form-validate>
            <input type="text" id="lastname-1" class="name-validator" name="Last Name">
        </div>
        <div class="remove">
            <a href="javascript:void(0);">X</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row-names" id="add-name2">
        <div class="firstname form-validate">
            <input type="text" id="firstname-2" class="name-validator" name="First Name" >
        </div><div class="lastname form-validate>
            <input type="text" id="lastname-2" class="name-validator" name="Last Name">
        </div>
        <div class="remove">
            <a href="javascript:void(0);">X</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row-names" id="add-name3">
        <div class="firstname form-validate">
            <input type="text" id="firstname-3" class="name-validator" name="First Name" >
        </div><div class="lastname form-validate>
            <input type="text" id="lastname-3" class="name-validator" name="Last Name">
        </div>
        <div class="remove">
            <a href="javascript:void(0);">X</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$('.remove a').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
});
```

Comment: you have unclose quote near `lastname form-validate` please fix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply remove the last row in the set - use the `X` as a general delete function rather than trying to target a specific row

**UPDATE**

Check the code below, you were adding handlers to each `X` every time you added a row, therefore adding multiple handlers - so, added a dynamic class to each `X` on row creation and then added handler for that

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var i = 2;
  $("#addMoreNames").click(function() {
    var temp_id = "add-name" + i;

    var firstNameInput = $('<div />', {
      'class': 'col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 campaign-firstname form-validate',
      'data-campaign-contact-id': i
    }).append('<div class="form-title">Given name</div>').append($("<input />", {
      type: "text",
      id: "campaign-firstname-" + i,
      class: "name-validator",
      name: "First Name",
      "data-firstname": "First name is missing"
    }));

    var lastNameInput = $("<div />", {
      'class': 'col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-5 campaign-lastname form-validate',
      'data-campaign-contact-id': i
    }).append('<div class="form-title">Family name</div>').append($("<input />", {
      type: "text",
      id: "campaign-lastname-" + i,
      class: "name-validator",
      name: "Last Name",
      "data-lastname": "Last name is missing"
    }));

    $("<div />", {
        "class": "row-names",
        id: "add-name" + i
      })
      .append(firstNameInput[0])
      .append(lastNameInput[0])
      .append('<div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1 remove-flight"><a href="javascript:void(0);" aria-label="Remove" class="remove-name' + i + '">X</a></div>')
      .appendTo("#add-more--names");

    $('.remove-flight .remove-name' + i).on('click', e => {
      e.preventDefault();
      $('#add-more--names').children().last().remove();
    });

    i++;
    if (i < 10) {
      $(this).show();
    } else {
      $(this).hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 campaign-firstname form-validate">
    <div class="form-title">Given name</div>
    <input class="name-validator" id="campaign-firstname-1" type="text" name="First Name" data-firstname="First name is missing">
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 campaign-lastname form-validate">
    <div class="form-title">Family name</div>
    <input class="name-validator" id="campaign-lastname-1" type="text" name="Last Name" data-lastname="Last name is missing">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row" id="add-more--names"></div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12"><a class="btn" id="addMoreNames" href="javascript:void(0);" aria-label="Add name"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"> </i>Add Name</a></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Dynamically i am adding these rows.. from using script "Add rows". If i implement this logic.. it works when i click last row. But, if i clicked any previous row, it removes all row

Comment: OK, your question doesn't say that so how can we know? You need to create a fiddle or snippet showing all the relevant code

Comment: - Any solution.. boss??

Comment: Updated answer @TDG